# Use of "/" in Oracle Statements

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have little experience in PL/SQL as I am much used to work on MySQL & MsSQL. Of course mostly I used to work on GUI but I know little SQL commands. I am learning Oracle now and got few samples from my friend and in that queries I am just wondering for what purpose / is used?

After few statements before the starting the next statement. In between I found he kept / in between. Of course I am not in a position to ask this doubt directly to him and started googling but didn't find any related. Can anybody tell me what's the use of a '/' in Oracle statements?

Comment: You can find this kind of thing out from the documentation, e.g. [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve004.htm), [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_four.htm#sthref278) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_four.htm#sthref293).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Executes the most recently executed SQL command or PL/SQL block which is stored in the SQL buffer.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12004.htm)